# List of all html entities as name value pairs

Tags: html, css, html-entities

I'm attempting to create css icon utilities that utilize html entities as the icon content.  Here's a [set of examples in my github repository](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-utilities-icons/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css) and here's one individual example:

```
.u-icon-olt {
    content: "⧀";
}


.u-icon-ogt {
    content: "⧁";
}
```

So far I have been adding each entity one by one as needed, but if I have a list of entities as key value pairs [olt: ⧀, ogt: ⧁, ...] then I can generate the above CSS.  Anyone know if there exists such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to do this, I'd parse the [reference at w3c](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Here's what that page looks [parsed into JSON](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/djtriptych/9e7f7b9f5161be4a2b59960ea4f448cf/raw/a53b420d9e1e997c44d09518f02d51712eba5a7b/entities.json).

And [here's the code](https://gist.github.com/djtriptych/9e7f7b9f5161be4a2b59960ea4f448cf#file-parse-py) I used to parse it (in python).

Comment: Yes that's precisely what I'm looking for.  The reference, but in a more consumable format.  Also since it's for web designers the shortest version of the name of each entity.

Comment: Wow - To say that i'm impressed would be a massive understatement - Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Note that I updated the JSON file (just before writing this comment) to fix a bug.

Comment: Thanks again for helping with this!  I now have the utillities on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/utilities-icons and here's a test showing their usage: https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-icons/target/test/html/